# How to search API response based from a define list

Tags: python

The code below grabs all data from an API response.

```
url = f"https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/ticker/24hr"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,timeout=1).json()

for item in response:
    token = item['symbol']
    priceChangePercent = item['priceChangePercent']
    count = item['count']
    volume = item['volume']
    quoteVolume = item['quoteVolume']
    print ("{} {} {} {} {}".format(token, priceChangePercent, count, volume, quoteVolume))
```

However, there are instances wherein not all the data are needed. How to search the response based on list

```
#-- to search from response
toSearch = ['APTUSDT', 'PHBBUSD','RUNEUSDT']
```

Needed Output:

```
APTUSDT   1,312,321     12,312      1,212,132   12,321,312.79
PHBBUSD     545,543     34,234         87,978        1,232.23
RUNEUSDT        344      8,543          2,357          943.45
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to do if the current item is not in the list?  Just skip it and go on to the next item?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `continue` statement that will skip the current item and proceed to the next one, if the item is not in the desired list.

```
for item in response:
    token = item['symbol']
    if token not in toSearch:
        continue
```